# How to switch between src images on error in Angular using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, image

I've been working on an Angular application for some time and I want to switch between multiple images when an error occurs. This is the code:

```
          <picture>
            <source [srcset]="element.thumbWebp" type="image/webp" />
            <source [srcset]="element.thumb" type="image/jpeg" />
            <source [srcset]="element.imageWebp" type="image/webp" />
            <img
              [src]="element.image"
              [alt]="element.title"
              height="204"
              width="145"
              onerror="this.onerror=; this.src='(DEFAULTIMAGELINKDELETEFORPRIVACY)';"
            />
          </picture>
            <script>
                function changeElement() {

                }
            </script>
```

The image should first chose "element.thumbWebp" then if an error occurs "element.thumb" then onerror "element.imageWebp and finally "element.image". The "element" code is a placeholder for logic in Angular that decides what image must be shown. I preferably want to do it via Javascript if this is possible? I've included a  tag with a function where it could be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript logical operation. OR.

element.thumbWebp || element.thumb || element.imageWebp || element.image

Comment: How do you mean? Where should I implement this?